# Check if a Key from dictionary is same as a dictionaries's key in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, count

I have a list

```
banned = []
```

and a tuple

```
address = ('127.0.0.1', 37670)
```

I'm accessing the first value (`ip`) as `address[0]`. So I inserted this `ip` to the new dictionary `banned_user` with a zero value for count.

```
banned_user = {adress[0]:0}
```

So I would like to know how to append `banned_user` to `banned` list if it not already contains. Like I'm doing like this

```
banned.append(banned_user.copy())
```

but I don't know how to check if `ip` from `banned_user` is in `banned`. If not I want to append it there with that `zero` value and if there is I want that `zero` to be +1 (plus). Can somebody please help me?

Comment: Why do you prefer to use a list of dictionaries? Why not just use a dictionary?

Comment: I'm expecting a lot of IP addresses inside, not only one

Comment: @MarcelKopera I think you are misunderstanding what dictionaries are. Dictionaries can store multiple key-value pairs, not just one.

Comment: You can add more that one IP to a dictionary. Here's a one liner:
`banned_user[ip] = banned_user.get(ip, 0) + 1`

Comment: ohh I see! thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a dictionary for `banned`, then lookup would be very fast. Since you're only using one part of the tuple (the string part) you could use that elements as the keys.

```py
banned = {}
address_tuple = ('127.0.0.1', 37670)

user_address, user_port = address_tuple

if user_address in banned:
    banned[user_address] += 1
else:
    banned[user_address] = 0
```